# Arduino Ver2.3.0 LTE Example LteGnssTrackerは正しく動かないままフリーズする

Tags: spresense

#### 動作確認

Arduino Ver2.2.1 LTE Example LteGnssTrackerを実行して、問題なく動作しましたが、
※EndPoint、User、Password、証明書などは正しく設定している。
同じなExampleでArduino Ver2.3.0にUpdateして、かつBootloaderにもUpadateしました。
再度確認したら、SerialMonitorからログはフリーズする。

LTE側のデグレかもしれないので、確認をいただけませんか。

**log**

```
Starting GNSS tracker via LTE.
DEBUG: Modem restart : 0
DEBUG: Successful modem poweron.
DEBUG: Successful start searching.
DEBUG: Successful get IMS capability : FALSE 
DEBUG: RAT changes are not supported in the FW version of the modem.
DEBUG: LTE_NET_RAT_CATM is already set on the modem.
Attempting to connect to network.
Gnss setup OK
Waiting for successful attach.
DEBUG: Report netinfo stat : 0
DEBUG: Report netinfo stat : 2
DEBUG: Report netinfo stat : 1
DEBUG: Successful PDN attach.
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 暫定対策

LTECore.cppのactivatePDNCallback()中のlte_set_report_netinfo(NULL)を削除して、解決できました。

#### 原因

modemStatusはLTE_CONNECTINGとなっているまま、LTE_READYにならないです。
なぜLTE_READYにならないかを調べてみたところで、activatePDNCallback()中のlte_set_report_netinfo(NULL)を実行すると、ずっとlte_set_report_netinfo(NULL)から抜けれないままで、theLTECore.setStatus(LTE_READY)を実行できませんでした。

#### activatePDNCallback登録流れ

下記の順にactivatePDNCallbackを登録しています。
attach→connectNetwork→lte_activate_pdn(&apnSetting, activatePDNCallback)

Answer (score 1):

ご指摘ありがとうございます。
LteGnssTrackerの不具合につきましては、Spresense Arduino v2.3.1で修正いたしました。
お手数をおかけいたしますが、こちらのバージョンをお使いいただけますでしょうか。

[Spresense Arduino v2.3.1リリースノート](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/releases/tag/v2.3.1)

今後もSPRESENSEをよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Spresense Arduino v2.3.1で確認しました。
特に問題ありません。
ありがとうございました。